# mongodb : update inner most element of nested array

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection named flowGraph which has one of the document structure as below:

```
{
    "_id": "565fafa4e4b02f4f9aa8feb4",
    "workSetup": false,
    "name": "somthing_name",
    "default": true,
    "active": true,
    "last_update": 1449111461492,
    "items": [{
        "characters": "ABC",
        "steps": [{
            "stepData": [{
                "stepName": "Step1",
                "index": 1,
                "stepDetails": [{
                    "flowText": "Activity for step 1",
                    "flowStatus": true
                }],
                "notes": ""
            }, {
                "stepName": "Step2",
                "index": 2,
                "stepDetails": [{
                    "flowText": "Activity for step 2",
                    "flowStatus": true
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "stepData": [{
                "stepName": "Function1",
                "index": 1,
                "stepDetails": [{
                    "flowText": "Default flow",
                    "flowStatus": true
                }]
            }, {
                "stepName": "Function2",
                "index": 2,
                "stepDetails": [{
                    "flowText": "Activity for Function2",
                    "flowStatus": true
                }]
            }]
        }, {

            "characters": "DEF",
            "steps": [{
                "stepData": [{
                    "stepName": "Procedure1",
                    "index": 1,
                    "stepDetails": [{
                        "flowText": "Default flow",
                        "flowStatus": true
                    }]
                }, {
                    "stepName": "Procedure2",
                    "index": 2,
                    "stepDetails": [{
                        "flowText": "Default flow",
                        "flowStatus": true
                    }]
                }]
            }, {
                "stepData": [{
                    "stepName": "Job1",
                    "index": 1,
                    "stepDetails": [{
                        "flowText": "Activity for Job1",
                        "flowStatus": true
                    }]
                }, {
                    "stepName": "Job2",
                    "index": 2,
                    "stepDetails": [{
                        "flowText": "Default flow",
                        "flowStatus": true
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

In the above json, i need to update all fields which match

```
"flowText": "Default flow"
```

To:

```
"flowText": "Active flow"
```

Since I am using a java application(using mongo java driver) to access it, I need to get this in one update query as I can not create a js file for executing this.
I am getting data if I execute below query.

```
db.flowGraph.find({"items.0.steps.0.stepData.1.stepDetails.0.flowText":"Default flow"});
```

I want it in a generic way so that i dont have to give the index directly.
If I do update as below it is not working:
Error: Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 
   db.flowGraph.update({"items.$.steps.$.stepData.$.stepDetails.$.flowText":"Default flow"},{$set:{"items.$.steps.$.stepData.$.stepDetails.$.flowText":"Active flow"}});

Questions:

1. **How can I find this document in first place with out giving the index as in items.0.steps.0.stepData.1.stepDetails.0.flowText**. Even if I find this, I have to iterate in loops and equals for the flowText, change it and save it back to DB
2. **How can I achieve to change flowText in a simpler way with out have to create a js file or going through multiple loops in java.**
3. **Is there any other way than using db.flowGraph.update?**

Note: I can't change the data structure of collection as there are so many other attributes in "steps" and "stepData" and I have removed those to simplify the problem.

Thanks for the help in advance!